# Why am I getting this java.io.exception "Can't allocate memory" from Hudson?

Tags: java, memory-management, hudson, hudson-plugins

Here's what I believe to be the relevant error message:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/git" (in directory "/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace"): java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:474)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:192)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:164)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:638)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:273)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:280)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:319)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:467)
    ... 21 more
```

You can also see the full output from Hudson here: http://hudson.pastebin.com/KLSNrY1D

Any ideas? How can I stop this from happening? I'm not a Java dev, so I don't know much about what's going on here. I have to restart Hudson entirely to fix the issue, but clearly this is not the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've exhausted swap space on your box.

The java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start() ultimately must boil down to a fork or clone system call on a Unix-like OS to create a new process.  That takes swap space.  And you seem to not have enough.  This is more in the Unix system admin realm, not Java.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running on Linode with 256 MB swap. I'd hesitate to think it's not enough for what I was doing (not very heavy lifting), but this is good to know for the future.

Comment: You're running Java based stuff and measuring memory in Mb?  Surprised this is the first time you're seeing this.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

For me:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How many external programs do you run at a time?  How many Hudson builders, etc?  What does "free" say when this happens?

You might simply have run into that the system has run out of memory available to the hudson process with children.

Comment: I run no external programs (Bugzilla's operating on a separate sub-domain, though that's not being used heavily). Hudson only runs a single build at once.

I'm not sure what you mean when you ask about "free"? Please do expand.

Comment: Under Linux there is usually a command named "free" which tells you a lot about memory usage.  You may want to have a look at that.